# Changing Column Names Based on a Different Dataframe

Tags: r

I have a data dictionary called `data_dict` of this format with hundreds of rows:

| Field Name | Field Label |
| --- | --- |
| marital_status | What is your marital status? |
| birthplace | What country were you born? |

I have another dataframe called `df` in this format with hundreds of rows:

| record_id | marital_status | birthplace |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 66 |
| 2 | 6 | 12 |

I am currently using `df %>% map(~ table(.x, useNA = "ifany"))` to summarize the results for all the columns in `df`. I want the `Field Label` column values from `data_dict` to appear instead of the column names from `df`. How could that be done without changing the column names in `df`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use `rename`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
 df %>% 
  summarise(across(all_of(data_dict$"Field Name"),
     ~ list(table(.x, useNA = "ifany")))) %>%
 rename(!!! deframe(data_dict[2:1]))
```

---

Or using `map`

```
library(purrr)
 df %>%
   rename(!!! deframe(data_dict[2:1])) %>%
   map(~ table(.x, useNA = "ifany"))
```

-output

```
$record_id
.x
1 2 
1 1 

$`What is your marital status?`
.x
3 6 
1 1 

$`What country were you born?`
.x
12 66 
 1  1
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(record_id = 1:2, marital_status = c(3L, 6L), birthplace = c(66L, 
12L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))

data_dict <- structure(list(`Field Name` = c("marital_status", "birthplace"
), `Field Label` = c("What is your marital status?", "What country were you born?"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: What does `df[2:1]` refer to when using `map()`? The thing is, in the actual `data_dict` file, `Field Name` is column 1 in the table, and `Field Label` is the 4th column in the table.

Comment: @fnaber If you have different columns, then you can also use `setNames(data_dict[[1]], data_dict[[4]])` instead of `deframe`